# How to Display only first 30 characters in Data table column and than place read more button next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i have json like this

[image]

as a result my datatable is looks like this

[image]

i want to display only 25 characters and than read more button next to display whole description, but i don't know how to do this,

here is my datatable implementation

```
$('#subsocieties-table').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/FrontEnd/resources/getsubsocieties?row='+row,
                dataSrc: '' 
            },

            "columns": [
                        { "data": "societyBlockId" },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "address" },
                        { "data": "description" }, // here in description i display now how to dispaly first 30 characters and than place read ore button in it ??
                        { "data": "launchDate" },
                        { "data": "blockByLawsFile" },
                        { "data": "blockFile" },
                        { "data": "type.name" },
                        { "data": "status.name" },

                              {
                                  "data": null,
                                  "className": "dt-center",
                                  searchable: false,

                                  orderable : false,
                                  render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                                      return '<a href="javascript:ShowBlockPPlanDetails('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Show Details</a>';
                          } },

                      {
                          "data": null,
                          "className": "dt-center",
                          searchable: false,

                          orderable : false,
                          render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                              return '<a href="javascript:ShowBlockFeaturesDetails('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Show Details</a>';
                  } },
                        {
                          "data": null,
                          "className": "dt-center",
                          searchable: false,
                          click: false, 
                          orderable : false,
                          render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                          return '<a href="javascript:editSubSocieties('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Edit</a> / <a href="javascript:removeSubSocieties('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Delete</a>';
                          } }
                       ] ,
                       "columnDefs": [
                                       {
                                           "targets": [ 0 ],
                                           "visible": false,
                                           "searchable": false
                                       }
                                       ,
                                  {
                                      "targets":5,
                                      "data": "download_link",
                                      "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {

                                     if(data != null)
                                         {
                                            var ext = data.split('.').pop();
                                        return '<a href="download.do?filename='+row.societyBlockId+'_blockbylawfile.'+ext+'">'+data+'</a>';
                                         }
                                     else
                                         {
                                            ext = data;
                                            return "";
                                         }


                                         }

                                    },
                                    {
                                        "targets":6,
                                        "data": "download_link",
                                        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                                         if(data != null)
                                     {
                                        var ext1 = data.split('.').pop();
                                    return '<a href="download.do?filename='+row.societyBlockId+'_blockfile.'+ext1+'">'+data+'</a>';
                                     }
                                 else
                                     {
                                        ext1 = data;
                                    return "";
                                     }

                                        }
                                    }
                                 ]
                });
```

Please let me know how to do this, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a plugin like :

- [dataTables.TruncateCells](https://bitbucket.org/JustinP8/datatables.truncatecells) - truncates each cell in a column down to a set number of characters, replacing the last 3 with an ellipses, and puts the full pre-truncated text in the cell's title attributed.

Comment: can you please provide assistance with code in my datatable implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option :

```
<td style=" max-width: 100px; 
            white-space: nowrap; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#example').dataTable({
            "data": responseObj,
            "columns": [
                            {
                                "data": "DT_RowId", "name": "DT_RowId", "orderable": false, "autoWidth": true, "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                    return "";
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Description", "name": "Description", "autoWidth": true , "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                   return fn(data, 100);

                              }
                            },

                        ]
                         function fn(Description, count) { return Description.slice(0, count) + (Description.length > count ? "..." : ""); }
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanations, so owner will understand why you are using this piece of code.